# How to pass parameters when initializing a library with Guice injection?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-8, guice, modularity

I have a library module which allows to connect to the database. For dependency injection I have used Guice in my module. This module will then be used by a service to connect to the database. In my library module I have a class that looks like this.

```
public class DatabaseDAO {
    

    @Inject
    private DatabaseClient dbclient;

    public CreateIndexResponse createIndex(final CreateIndexData createIndexData) throws IOException {
        return dbclient.create(createIndexData)
    }

    public DBIndexResponse indexDocument(final String indexName, final String jsonDocument) throws IOException {
        return dbclient.index(indexName, jsonDocument);
    }

}
```

The dbClient object above then gets injected through a Guice provider as shown below in my Guice module class.

```
public class DatabaseModule extends AbstractModule {
    private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "myService";
    private static final String ENDPOINT = "myEndpoint";

   
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(DatabaseDAO.class).toInstance(new DatabaseDAO());
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DatabaseClient provideDBClient(final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) {
        SomeObject someObject = doSomething(credentialsProvider, SERVICE_NAME, ENDPOINT);
        return new DatabaseClient(someObject);
    }
}
```

Currently I left the SERVICE_NAME variable and ENDPOINT variables in the DatabaseModule however I would like to have them inserted by the service that uses this library. In the way the code is now, the service will initiate the DatabaseDAO as following.

```
 Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new DatabaseModule());
 dbDAO = injector.getInstance(DatabaseDAO.class);
```

However when the service creates the injector like above, I'd like to pass the values for those variables so that the person using the library has control. How can I achieve this with Guice? Any help and guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Assisted injection. https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject

Comment: The examples on assisted injection don't seem to elaborate on how I can pass the name parameter values from the service. They seem to show how I can use assisted inject within the library module itself :(

Comment: You inject the factory and pass in the parameters to the creation method.

Comment: I have one more question @BoristheSpider. Currently the DatabaseModule class provides the db client to DatabaseDAO class. With AssistedInject I'll have a constructor in DatabaseDAO and provide the two variables. How can I then pass it to DatabaseModule to fetch the db client object? OR should I make some changes here about how DatabaseDAO gets the db client?